# Julia: How can I update my published julia package?

Tags: package, julia, github-actions, julia-pkg

I'm trying to develop my first Julia package, [FeatureEng.jl](https://github.com/a-poor/FeatureEng.jl) but I'm having trouble updating the package on the registry.

I've set up the GitHub actions TagBot and Register and tried updating the package version via the Project.toml file and via git tags, but I still only have one release on GitHub ("v1.0.1") and I get the following output from TagBot:

```
Tag v1.0.1 already exists
```

When I run my package in its own environment and check the version I get...

```
julia> using Pkg
julia> Pkg.activate(".")
Activating environment at `~/Desktop/code/julia/FeatureEng/Project.toml`
julia> using FeatureEng, PkgVersion
julia> PkgVersion.Version(FeatureEng)
v"1.2.7"
```

but when I install my package in a separate environment, from the general registry, and run the same check I get...

```
julia> PkgVersion.Version(FeatureEng)
v"1.0.1"
```

Am I missing something? What is the right way to publish a new Julia package version?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When your version is 1.0.1 your next version can only be 1.0.2 or 1.1.0 or 2.0.0

Comment: Przemyslaw Szufel Thanks -- I accidentally skipped "v1.1.0". What is the official way you're supposed to upgrade a package? Via git tags? Via Project.toml?

Comment: `@JuliaRegistrator register`  you got nice answer already :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Be sure you have the tagbot file on your repository
2. Upgrade the version number in your local Project.toml file
3. Commit and push to GitHub
4. In GitHub, add a comment to the commit with the text `@JuliaRegistrator register`
5. That's all. Tagbot will automatically create the same tag on GitHub.

Fore more details, you can have a look on my tutorial on modules and packages: https://syl1.gitbook.io/julia-language-a-concise-tutorial/language-core/11-developing-julia-packages